# How to stop Windows from overriding a DHCP assigned hostname?

Tags: windows, networking, hostname

At my university the DHCP server assigns each computer a unique hostname. On a unix box, you can type hostname and see this unique hostname (it is essentially your IP address). On a windows box however, the computer name overrides this hostname, and a call to hostname in the command window will return your computer name.

I cannot simply change the Windows box's computer name to match the hostname it should have because the DHCP server assigns hostnames with periods(.). Anyone know how to stop windows from doing this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Windows' DHCP client doesn't support the Host Name option (even though their DHCP server does).

To see a list of the [RFC 1533](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1533) DHCP options supported by Windows DHCP client [see here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121005/EN-US/).

> Protocol Options:
>
> - DHCP message type
> - Lease Time
> - Renewal Time
> - Rebind Time
>
> Informational Options
>
> - Subnet Mask
> - Default Router
> - DNS Server
> - Domain Name
> - WINS Server
> - NetBIOS Node Type
> - NetBIOS Scope Id
> - Router Discovery
> - Classless route
> - Static router